# How to make sure that Collections in java hold only one Type?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I want to make sure that a Collection can hold only one Type.

Lets say there is such a method.

```
public Collection<Students> getStudents();
```

One can write following code.

```
Collection students = getStudents();
students.add(new Book());
```

`Book` does not extend `Student`. Now the Collection students contains a wrong Object.
How can I make sure that this line `Collection students = getStudents();` is not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enforce it at runtime if you use [Collections.checkedCollection()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Class%29) every time you instantiate a Collection. Admittedly it would be a bit painful. :)

Answer (score 13):

This is called a [*raw type*](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Raw%20Types). Raw types were introduced for backward compatibility - so that old code still worked against newer JDKs, basically.

You can make `javac` warn about the use of raw types using `-Xlint:rawtypes`, and in IDEs you may be able to make it an actual error, but it's still fundamentally valid Java.

Comment: Mr. Skeet. Out of curiosity. As a Java developer do you actually use IDEs like Eclipse or Netbeans? This is not a joke question.

Comment: @RAM: Personally I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

Jon Skeet made the right answer. You can define your Java Compiler on Properties (Or Project-Properties) to get an error if you use a raw-type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use this format :

```
    Collection<Students> s = students.getStudents();
```